# Why are users id being undefined for discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Ok so I've been working with someone on a discord leveling system, and we are SO close to done, but when we make the leaderboard it constantly pops up with the error, "cannot read property of tag of undefined".  We want to be able to use peoples discord names, rather than just their id, that way it's easier to know who is who on the leaderboard.  We have tried many different things to replace this, but just can't seem to figure it out.  I know that the issue is some users ids being undefined, thus the bot is unable to find their tag, im just unsure why some users id are being undefined in the first place.  If you know a solution please let me know, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
const XP = require('quick.xp');
const xp = new XP.SQLiteManager({
deleteMessage: false
})

client.on('message', (message) => {
    const level = xp.getLevel(message, message.author.id)
    const userxp = xp.getXP(message, message.author.id)
    if (message.author.bot) {
      return;}
    else {
      xp.giveXP(message);
    }
    if (message.content === "?rank") message.channel.send(`You are on level ${level} and have ${userxp} XP`)
    if (message.content === "?leaderboard") {
        let lb = xp.leaderboard(message, message.guild.id, {limit: 10, raw: false});
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Leaderboard")
        .setColor("#FFFFFF")
        lb.forEach(m => {
            embed.addField(`${m.position}. ${client.users.cache.get(m.id).tag}`, `Level: ${xp.getLevel(message, m.id)}\n XP: ${m.xp}`)
        })
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
    if (level === '10') {
      member.role.add('788820930331017244')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Only `.tag` you try to acces in this code is:

```
embed.addField(`${m.position}. ${client.users.cache.get(m.id).tag}`, `Level: ${xp.getLevel(message, m.id)}\n XP: ${m.xp}`)
```

That means there is undefined returned from: `client.users.cache.get(m.id)`

As you have not provided this function just from the code here i can tell that function returns undefined - maybe if couldnt not find the given m.id in cache?

You should have some protection against such code for example

```
const userFromCache = client.users.cache.get(m.id);
embed.addField(`${m.position}. ${(userFromCache ? userFromCache.tag : '-- no tag --'}`, `Level: ${xp.getLevel(message, m.id)}\n XP: ${m.xp}`);
```